# Installing g++ compiler on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: c++, ubuntu, g++

I have installed ubuntu 13.04 on my machine recently. But when I try to run c++ code it gives error. I tried with this command 
"sudo apt-get install g++" but failed to install it completely.
Please help me.

Comment: You need to be more specific. What error did you get when you run "sudo apt-get install g++"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got same error while installing g++ on my machine. Then I searched on google. I tried different commands but couldn't succeeded. During this I got a pretty good answer which helps in all g++ installing errors. 
Go to "System Settings" . At the end of window there is a option "Software  & updates ".
Then in "Ubuntu Software" tab there is a opttion  "Download from" then by clicking it select "main server". Now run your command "sudo apt-get install g++".

Comment: Thanks bro. I was surprised to see my friend on stackoverflow.

Comment: You was able to answer your question by your original account, you didn't have to make a new account.